# SQL - How can I Increment a field in a results set by 1 for every 10 records returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Increment a field in a results set by 1 for every 10 records returned?

So the first ten items will have a field called "BoxNumber" and that value will be 1. items 11-20 will have BoxNumber = 2

etc

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data.

Comment: My vote is this shouldn't be managed in the data layer; the consuming application should be responsible for numbering as rows come in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        BoxNumber = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1)-1)/10+1
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Fantastic response. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to avoid doing this in my data layer as i'm dealing with large amounts of data